# Highlight places in Python Cartopy maps

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I am still confused by some aspects of Cartopy. I don't understand why some instructions don't work... For example, if I want to draw a map of Great Britain, I can use the program below, and I get my map.

I understand that the `Orthographic` projection uses degrees for longitude and latitude, so I set `extent = [-6.5, 3.5, 49.5, 59.0]` to limit my map, where `-6.5` means `6.5°` of Eastern longitude and `3.5` means `3.5°` of western longitude, etc.

For that, if I want to highlight Greenwich on the map, I think straight away that I have first to define its coordinates: `Greenwich_lon, Greenwich_lat = 0.0, 51.0`, and then to plot these coordinates: `ax.plot(Greenwich_lon, Greenwich_lat, marker='x', markersize=12, color='red')`.

But this gives me a point on the map that is completely **outside** the right place!

Why is it so? Does it come from `ax.plot` which is not appropriate? Does it come from the positioning of parameters `Greenwich_lon` and `Greenwich_lat` in `ax.plot` (I reversed them, but nothing changed)? Does it come from some instruction missing in `ax.plot`? Does it come from the projection system used?

Where could I find explanations expressed simply, with examples? I know that Cartopy has a huge documentation [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html), but it's so vast that I am lost more than anything else...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.feature as cf
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

extent = [-6.5, 3.5, 49.5, 59.0]
central_lon = np.mean(extent[:2])
central_lat = np.mean(extent[2:])

proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_lon, central_lat)

ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.gridlines()

border = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
    'cultural', 'admin_0_boundary_lines_land', scale='110m') 
land = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
    'physical', 'land', scale='110m', 
    edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land'])
ocean = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
    'physical', 'ocean', scale='110m', 
    edgecolor='none', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['water'])

ax.add_feature(border) 
ax.add_feature(land) 
ax.add_feature(ocean) 

Greenwich_lon, Greenwich_lat = 0.0, 51.0

ax.plot(Greenwich_lon, Greenwich_lat, marker='x', markersize=12, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Add this option `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` to `ax.plot()`. It transforms lat/long degrees to projection coordinates, and plots at the intended position.

Comment: In `.set_extent()` the default ccrs is lat/long in degrees, so you can skip the option `crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartopy always plot in `projection` coordinates (same as `data` coordinates in Matplotlib). In general, it accepts input data in most projection coodinates with options that specifies the coordinate system the data is based on.

It is your responsible to use correct values with accompanying options.
For example, if XXXX() is the map projection coordinates your data is based on,

```
.set_extent(lon_min, lon_max, lat_min, lat_max, crs=cartopy.crs.XXXX())

.plot(lon, lat, marker'x', transform=cartopy.crs.XXXX())
```

If you use lat/long in degrees, you can use PlateCarree() in place of XXXX() above.
However, for convenient reasons, .set_extent() has crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree() as a default option that you usually omit.

For further information about coordinate system and tranformation:

Cartopy
https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html
Since Cartopy is built on top of Matplotlib, you need to look into the related subject in Matplotlib.

Matplotlib
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: OK @swatchai, it allows me to better understand what's going on. Thanks for the specific links that I will read carefully.